# sqlite query order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

### lastname | name | company

I want to order by lastname (if not empty), name (if not empty), company (never empty) like this

### lastname | name | company

```
a    |   b  |    a
a    |   b  |    b
a    |   b  |    c
     |   a  |    a
     |   a  |    b
     |   a  |    c
     |      |    a
b    |   a  |    a
b    |   b  |    a
b    |   c  |    a
     |   b  |    a
     |   b  |    b
     |   b  |    c
     |      |    b
c    |   a  |    a
c    |   b  |    a
c    |   c  |    a
     |   c  |    a
```

ecc...

What is the right code?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` which returns the first non-null argument.

```
order by coalesce(lastname,name,company)
```

Comment: @VincenzoPutignano Note that the assumption (quite reasonably) is that 'empty' equals `NULL`

Comment: This results in a random order for rows (b,b) and (b,c).

Comment: @VincenzoPutignano.. the result you are looking for is impossible to get. Why would `(null,a,a)` appear after lastname `a` group,(null,'b','c')  after lastname `b` group? One way is to order all rows with null in first column, then with nulls in 2nd column, then by the last column.